# What is logic to construct a binary tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have a while loop which continuously takes integers until -1 is entered. Those elements must be inserted into a binary tree (not a BST). If it was a BST, we have a condition for where to insert the new node. But how can I construct a binary tree?

I mean if nodes are 1,2,3,4,5,6..., then 
1 is the root, 2 and 3 are the left and right children of node 1,
4 and 5 are the left and right children of node 2, and 6 is left child of node 3, like this:

```
if(root==NULL)
    root= newnode; 
else{
    if (root->left==NULL) 
        root->left= insert(root->left,element); 
    else 
        root->right= insert(root->right,element); 
}
return root;
```

How do I create a tree like this?

Comment: What is the background? If there is no limits/condition. You can do whatever you like, as long as it satisfies the definition of binary tree.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Is it necessary to use a node based tree?

Comment: You have to specify how many leafs does tree have. In your case it has 2 leafs.

Comment: Please don't tag spam.

Comment: Yes. I should use linked list to implement. Or if you any other logic, tell me atleast,  I will learn that one.

Comment: The simple tree you're describing of 1->(2,3), 2->(4,5), 3->(6,7), etc... can easily be managed in an array. It doesn't even require a node-pointer-based structure. It is frequently used when manufacturing a [*binary heap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation) due to indexing efficiency, among other reasons. Given any node in the tree at slot `n`, it's children will be in slots `(2n+1)`, and `2(n+1)`, assuming a zero-based indexing system.

Comment: @WhozCraig Seems like OP wants to add nodes dynamically. How would an array support that? Using `realloc()`?

Comment: @babon I never saw anything in the OPs description about continuous dynamic management. In fact, the only example in the woefully-under-described and over-tagged post would lend itself *exactly* to the management I mentioned. Of course, if the elements are truly delivered in breadth-first order and a node-pointer system was *mandated* to be used, one could use an intermediate node-pointer queue to do it. Seems a bit overkill, but certainly doable.

Comment: Are you learning C or C++?  Choose one, not both.  The answer in C++ is (radically) different from the answer in C.

Comment: I am learning C++.

Comment: @WhozCraig: it would be oh so tempting to do as you suggest — allocate the data in an array of the node structures, and then fix up the pointers so that the links are correct.  It's almost trivial.  Since the OP has chosen to learn C++ (but is presumably not allowed to use an 'STL' solution), `realloc()` is a nuisance, but a vector of pointers to nodes could hold the data as it arrives, and then the links could be fixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm outlined by [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686957/what-is-logic-to-construct-a-binary-tree#comment78332103_45686957) can be realized by the code:

```
/* Create a binary tree with nodes presented in BFS order */
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::ostream;
using std::setw;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node(int n) : data(n), left(0), right(0) { }
};

void print_bt(const node *root);

int main()
{
    vector<node> v;
    int n;

    // Read data to EOF or a negative value
    while (cin >> n && n >= 0)
        v.push_back(node(n));

    // Create binary tree
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size()/2; i++)
    {
        assert(2*i+1 < v.size());
        v[i].left = &v[2*i+1];
        if (2*i+2 < v.size())
            v[i].right = &v[2*i+2];
    }

    // Print binary tree
    print_bt(&v[0]);

    return 0;
}

// print_bt() presents the data so that if you mentally rotate the
// output through 90º clockwise (so the root is at the top), then the
// left child appears on the left and the right on the right.  Reversing
// the order of left/right leaves that as somewhat confusing.
void print_bt(const node *root)
{
    static int level = 0;
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        level++;
        print_bt(root->right);
        cout << setw(4*level) << root->data << '\n';
        print_bt(root->left);
        level--;
    }
}
```

For example, given the numbers 1 to 6 as input, it produces:

```
       3
           6
   1
           5
       2
           4
```

and given the numbers 1 to 15 as input, it produces:

```
              15
           7
              14
       3
              13
           6
              12
   1
              11
           5
              10
       2
               9
           4
               8
```

It helps if you visualize the tree rotated 90º clockwise, so that the `1` is at the top.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way of doing this is use ***level order traversal***. 
Whenever you find a node whose left or right child is NULL, attach the new node as a child of that node; if both left and right are NULL, attach as left child, else attach as right child.

```
tree_node *insert_node_in_tree(tree_node *root, node new_node) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return new_node;

    queue <tree_node * > qu;
    tree_node *temp;
    qu.push(root);

    while(!(qu.empty())) {
        temp = qu.front();
        qu.pop();

        if(temp->left == NULL || temp->right == NULL)
            break;
        qu.push(temp->left);
        qu.push(temp->right);

    }

    if(temp->left == NULL)
        temp->left = new_node;
    else
        temp->right = new_node;

    return root;
}
```

Comment: Would the loop look better if you used `if (temp->left == NULL || temp->right == NULL) break;` and left the pushes at the same level of indent as the `if`?

Comment: An alternative to this can be done *very* efficiently using a queue to hold pointers to `Node` pointers, and simply streaming the input data directly into the tree. [See example here](http://ideone.com/pnRmSi). Note: not really high-quality code, but demonstrates how you can use the same queue concept to stream data directly into the tree without repetitive iteration, as well as for level order enumeration.